# Solidity issue passing parameters to a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask

I have a Smart Contract with the function:

```
contract Example {
     event claimed(address owner);
     function claimStar() public {
          owner = msg.sender;
          emit claimed(msg.sender);
     }
}
```

I'm using Truffle V5.0 and the Webpack box as a boiler plate code.

In my `truffle-config.js` file I have the in the networks configuration:

```
development:{
  host:"127.0.0.1",
  port: 9545,
  network_id:"*"
}
```

Everything compile fine using:
- `truffle develop`
- `compile`
- `migrate --reset`
It says `Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545`

In my index.js file I have the following code:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import starNotaryArtifact from "../../build/contracts/StarNotary.json";

const App = {
  web3: null,
  account: null,
  meta: null,

  start: async function() {
    const { web3 } = this;

    try {
      // get contract instance
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = starNotaryArtifact.networks[networkId];
      this.meta = new web3.eth.Contract(
        starNotaryArtifact.abi,
        deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // get accounts
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      this.account = accounts[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Could not connect to contract or chain.");
    }
  },

  setStatus: function(message) {
    const status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = message;
  },

  claimStarFunc: async function(){
    const { claimStar } = this.meta.methods;
    await claimStar();
    App.setStatus("New Star Owner is " + this.account + ".");
  }

};

window.App = App;

window.addEventListener("load", async function() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    // use MetaMask's provider
    App.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    await window.ethereum.enable(); // get permission to access accounts
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live",);
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    App.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:9545"),);
  }

  App.start();
});
```

In my browser I have Metamask installed and I added a Private Network with the same URL and also imported two accounts.
When I start the application and opened in the browser it opens Metamask to request permission because I'm using `window.ethereum.enable();`.
But when I click on the button to `claim` it doesn't do anything.
The normal behavior is to Metamask open a prompt to ask for confirmation but it never happen.
I created also a new property in the contract for test and it works fine showing me the value assigned in the contract constructor.
My question is, Am I missing something?

I also tried to change the function`await claimStar();` to `await claimStar({from: this.account});` but in this case I got an error saying that `claimStar` doesn't expect parameters.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem was in the function `claimStarFunc`
It should be in this way:

```
claimStarFunc: async function(){
    const { claimStar } = this.meta.methods;
    await claimStar().send({from:this.account});
    App.setStatus("New Star Owner is " + this.account + ".");
  }
```

Because I'm sending a transaction.
Thanks